# How to handle more than one request defined in a dynamic script

Tags: javascript, html, json, function, google-api

My intention is to get 50 images from google search using API .As you know this Api can give 10 results at a time. I prefer multiple calls within this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var item = new Array();
  var i=j=1;

  function hndlr(response) {
    while(response.items[i]!=null){
      item[i]= response.items[i].image.thumbnailLink;
      i++;
      j=i;
        }
 }


function load_page()
{

    var value=document.getElementById("query").value;

      var r1 = document.createElement("script");
    r1.type = "text/javascript";
    r1.src = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=***&q="+value +"&searchType=image&stop=5&callback=hndlr";

    r1.innerHTML = null;
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(r1);
    i=1;
    test();
}
```

Now this code is to handle a single  Custom search Api request. How can I extend this code so that it can give out multiple request and for each request I can handle response using a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the image search api which has higher limit of 64 results per request. 
You can find the explanation needed [here](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide) as well as the fact of the limitation.

Please note though that this is deprecated and limited with number of requests made.

You can also look [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#wsRequestLimits) for something that isn't deprecated. Also notice that the link I provided directs you to the solution of your issue.